# pgfplots package, error bars, moved when second series is added

Tags: pgfplots

I have got a problem. When I add the second series to my plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2G6z.png), the error bars from the first series moved from their original position [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfx6.png). I use pgfplots package.

Plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2G6z.png): 
[image]

Plot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfx6.png):
[image]

Thanks for help in advance.

Below I attach the fragment of code:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={xxxxxxx},
ylabel={xxxxxxx}, ybar, xticklabels={,,},ymin=17,
ymax=21,
xmin=0,
xmax=8,
ystep=1,
ytick={0,1,...,25},
xtick={0,...,8},
axis y line = left, axis x line = bottom]
\addplot+[only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y=exp, y error=err]
{
cfd exp err
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
};
\addplot+[only marks]
table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y=cfd]
{
cfd exp err
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
18 20 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xxxxxxx}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Just a note: You should avoid the env `{center}` inside of floating env, since it adds (probably unwanted) vertical spacing. Instead replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ybar` from the `axis` options. Even if the bars are not drawn or filled, they have a width (default 10pt) and the bars of different plots in the same axis are shifted. The error bars are centered horizontally to the plotted bars.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={xxxxxxx},
      ylabel={xxxxxxx},
      %ybar,% <- remove this 
      xticklabels={,,},
      ymin=17,
      ymax=21,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=8,
      ystep=1,
      ytick={0,1,...,25},
      xtick={0,...,8},
      axis y line = left,
      axis x line = bottom
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
      table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y=exp, y error=err]
      {
        cfd exp err
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
    };
    \addplot+[only marks]
      table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y=cfd]
      {
        cfd exp err
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
        18 20 1
    };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{xxxxxxx}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]